# check if a latitude longitude lies on a line between two cordinates

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geospatial, geo

[image: 1 coordinate between two]

I've 3 coordinates with their latitude and longitude. If a line is drawn from A to B, I want to check if the third point is exactly on the line drawn from A and B.

or we can rephrase this question as: connecting three coordinates should give me a straight line and not a triangle.

I only want to do this calculation on server.

Comment: Define "straight line".  (Hint: the earth is not flat ...)

Comment: In case you are willing to sacrifice some accuracy or the distance between the coordinates isn't that large, I guess you could use simple triangular geometry. That is, use the length (i.e. in meters) between {AB,AC,BC} to find the height of the triangle made by the three points. The lower the height the better point 'fits' onto the line segment made by A and B.

Comment: Another, possibly even simpler idea: isOntheLine = (dist(A,B) ~= dist(A,C)+dist(C,B)) , again using a ~ to express that you cannot expect it to be exact. Rather having a margin of error that is accepted due to projection during distance calculations etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
public static boolean onLine(LatLng A, LatLng B, LatLng C) {
    double m1 = (C.latitude - A.latitude)/(C.longitude - A.longitude);
    double m2 = (C.latitude - B.latitude)/(C.longitude - B.longitude);
    return m1 == m2;
}
```

Comment: This will not work very well when you're near to the poles or if A and B are very far away from each other! The earth is round!

Comment: I agree. However, if the requirement is to check whether co-ordinates lie on a straight line, it is reasonable to assume that the co-ordinates are close to each other. If not, a straight line makes no sense.

Comment: I'm trying this logic in Swift. But, it is not working. Every time it is returning false. I also need to check does my coordinate lie in straight line or not